# ImportError nltk.corpus :pil

Tags: python, pycharm, nltk, importerror

I cannot import pil (The Patient Information Leaflet (PIL) Corpus) and I already checked my nltk's version is 3.2.5.

```
    import nltk
    from nltk.corpus import pil
```

I can import other corpus libraries (like brown, twitter_samples etc), but I have no idea why I cannot import this one >.<

```
    from nltk.corpus import pil
    ImportError: cannot import name pil
```

The downloader shows this package has downloaded.

[downloader screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e5bt.png)

Comment: what is the name of your file that you are trying to run?

Comment: You can download from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/corpora/pil.zip). But first [try the interactive installer as it may be a simple issue of needing to download it first (I don't believe they all get downloaded initially)](http://www.nltk.org/data.html)

Comment: Interesting... There's no corpus reader for pil?!

Comment: Thanks @Cleo for spotting thing! Raised issue on https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1851

Comment: @Dan I've downloaded it in the "nltk_data" folder, but it still not working.